# error TS2339: Property 'currentVersion' does not exist on type 'typeof ClientSchemaVersions'

Tags: sharepoint, typescript

I am using `reference path="../typings/sharePoint/sharePoint.d.ts"`
and the file has:

```
export class ClientSchemaVersions {
    version14: string;
    version15: string;
    currentVersion: string;
```

But the statement `parseInt(SP.ClientSchemaVersions.currentVersion)` complains Property 'currentVersion' does not exist on type 'typeof ClientSchemaVersions'
but works right at run time.
On the other hand, the code:

```
let mySP = new SP.ClientSchemaVersions();
console.log(mySP.currentVersion)
```

Does not error in typescript but at run time, the value of `mySP.currentVersion` is undefined.
Is there a setting to set in the config files?

Answer (score 0):

`SP.ClientSchemaVersions.currentVersion` is defined if and only if `currentVersion` is a static class variable of `SP.ClientSchemaVersions`. In this case, the definition file for sharePoint may be wrong. You should fire an issue.
  As for `let mySP = new SP.ClientSchemaVersions();`, if `currentVersion` is a static variable of class `SP.ClientSchemaVersions`, it will not appear on `SP.ClientSchemaVersions.prototype`. I guess, `SP.ClientSchemaVersions.currentVersion = "1.2.3"` is in their js code. So, `currentVersions` is not on the prototype chains of `mySP`.